# caught SIGTERM error PHP FAST-CGI APACHE Ubuntu14.4

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04

I installed PHP 5.2.17 as per the following tutorial

http://zgadzaj.com/how-to-install-php-53-and-52-together-on-ubuntu-1204

apt-get installed PHP5.5 and apache 2.4.7

PHPINFO reports that the php version of the set host is still 5.5.9

when I restart apache2 service, I get the following in error.log.

```
[Thu Mar 19 14:18:53.648697 2015] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 23518] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Thu Mar 19 14:18:54.741836 2015] [:notice] [pid 5543] FastCGI: process manager initialized (pid 5543)
[Thu Mar 19 14:18:54.754243 2015] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 5541] AH00163: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) mod_fastcgi/mod_fastcgi-SNAP-0910052141 PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.6 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Mar 19 14:18:54.754317 2015] [core:notice] [pid 5541] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
```

Comment: Removing php5.5 solved the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing `php5.5` solved the problem.

The problem probably was a conflict between the two `PHP` versions, using *same* `fastcgi` implementation.